# strSQL between date range excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to run an strSQL within Excel VBA between two date ranges.

See below part of my code relevant to this:

```vb
Dim DateMin As String
Dim DateMax As String

DateMin = Format$(Sheets("Setup").Range("c5").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")        
DateMax = Format$(Sheets("Setup").Range("c6").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")

strSQL = "SELECT [COSTCENTRE_CODE],[PROJECT_CODE],[HOME_VALUE],[CT_DEADLINE] FROM [AA_CST_CENTRE_TRANSACTION_SIMPLE_VIEW] where [CT_DEADLINE] between #" & DateMin & "# AND #" & DateMax & "#"
```

When I run this I get an "incorrect syntax nea '#'" error. The format of cells C5 + C6 are in the same mm/dd/yyyy format - am using the American date format as believe SQL only uses American dates? I have tried adjusting the dates but no luck.

When I run "debug.print strsql" I get the below:

```sql
SELECT [COSTCENTRE_CODE],[PROJECT_CODE],[HOME_VALUE],[CT_DEADLINE] FROM [AA_CST_CENTRE_TRANSACTION_SIMPLE_VIEW] where [CT_DEADLINE] between #02/01/2020# AND #03/31/2020#
```

I have tried removing the `#` around the dates and I no longer get the error, however no data shows at all - there is definitely data there for these dates.

Anyone have any ideas as believe this is an SQL issue rather than an Excel VBA issue?

Comment: I have now managed to fix this by using the following code: strSQL = "SELECT COSTCENTRE_CODE,PROJECT_CODE,HOME_VALUE,CT_DEADLINE FROM AA_CST_CENTRE_TRANSACTION_SIMPLE_VIEW where CT_DEADLINE between '" & DateMin & "' and '" & DateMax & "'" the date format needs to be m/d/yyyy for the cell range

Answer (score 1):

Does running this SQL work? `SELECT [COSTCENTRE_CODE],[PROJECT_CODE],[HOME_VALUE],[CT_DEADLINE] FROM [AA_CST_CENTRE_TRANSACTION_SIMPLE_VIEW]` just to make sure the issue is in the date part and not before. If this is not running then the issue is in this part and not in the date part.

And I believe SQL is using `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss` as date format. Check that out if you have done the first suggested test and this query runs.

And as far as I know only Access accepts `#` but in SQL-Server you would neet to use `'` instead (which should also work for Access).

Also note that

```
BETWEEN '02/01/2020' AND '03/31/2020'
```

is actually:

```
BETWEEN '02/01/2020 00:00:00.000' AND '03/31/2020 00:00:00.000'
```

So notice that you are missing anything that happened after 12am on `03/31/2020`.

Comment: Running the SQL without the date does work and copies the data into Excel, so is definitely a date issue.

I have added "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss" within the DateMin and DateMax part of the VBA and I have also changed the cell format to "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss" but now I get an "incorrect syntax near '00'" error.....i've also removed the "#" and using " instead but still the same syntax error

Comment: I have had another play around and it's definitely the DateMin/DateMax that is the issue as if I run the below code it works!!

strSQL = "SELECT [COSTCENTRE_CODE],[PROJECT_CODE],[HOME_VALUE],[CT_DEADLINE] FROM [AA_CST_CENTRE_TRANSACTION_SIMPLE_VIEW] where CT_DEADLINE='06/19/2008'"


It's just when I put in the between DateMin and DateMax is where I get the problem.........(sorry I don't know how to format the comments to show this reply better!)

Comment: If you use it like this `BETWEEN '02/01/2020' AND '03/31/2020'` what is the error message you get? And please edit your original question and add the information where exactly you run this query (and how, show the complete relevant code part) and where is the data you want to query? Reading [mcve] might help to improve your question. Also make sure that the data is actually a date and not a text looking like a date because `Between` does not work on text.